# How can I use youtube in pi?

Tags: streaming-video

How can I play YouTube videos on a Raspberry Pi?

I tried to play in the chromium browser, but it doesn't work there.

Comment: The chromium browser needs to be the later version 45-ish one AND the RPi should be a quad-core RPi 2.  The version that once worked for the single-core RPi was 23 (I think) and I suspect YouTube have changed their formats enough to stop it working (*I expect, but do not **know***)

Comment: What version do you have? My chromium works perfectly fine with youtube.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method I can think of is using Kodi. This *should* work to a reasonable degree on lower end Pi's.

1. Install Kodi using 'sudo apt-get install kodi'
2. Go to System -> Settings
3. Go to Add-ons
4. Select 'Install from repository'
5. Select 'Kodi Add-on repository
6. Select 'Video add-ons'
7. Select 'Youtube'
8. Set up language and region
9. To launch the add-on, go to the home screen and select 'Videos -> Add-ons -> YouTube'

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Chromium, but YouTube videos should work under Epiphany and Ice-Weasel. On the RPi, you'll want to view the videos under HTML5.  Use YouTube's [HTML5 compatibility checker](https://www.youtube.com/html5) to make sure it's supported in your desired browser.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [**Minimal Kiosk Browser**](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=40860) ("kweb" and "kweb3") .

It has extra **helper scripts** to play youtube in **1080@30** fps , which sets it apart from all browsers which use gstreamer on the Pi Zero or on RPi1 models.

It also includes a GUI for omxplayer , which is very useful.

It is  a bit unorthodox and highly customizable , so don't forget to read the manual !

Answer (score 1):

You can get Youtube alternatives on Rasbian OS .
You can try downloading Youtubuddy .
Try typing commands ,Download [Pi-apps](https://github.com/Botspot/pi-apps)

and If it shows "pi-apps update available", that means the install is succesful.
click on pi apps icon , click Run in terminal if it asks where to run , then pi apps will open . Go to "all apps" -> "Youtubuddy" -> "install" .
When you open youtubuddy , It will look like a degraded rpi version for youtube.
Hope you enjoy watching youtube videos !

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on raspberry pi2. Chromium was playing the video but it was black and white and messy.(ubuntu-mate)

**Solution :**

Update your Mozilla Firefox  browser :https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/update-firefox-latest-version

I can play at 144/240/360 but it's still lags between audio and video.